# Mysql getting first and last record of grouping

Tags: mysql, subquery, grouping

I have an issue with a query I'm not able to figure out how to perform.

let me simplify the table structure;

```
|-------------|--------|
| node_id     |  id    |
| 2610        |  1643  |
| 2610        |  1644  |
| 2610        |  1645  |
| 2610        |  1646  |
| 2611        |  1647  |
| 2611        |  1648  |
```

and so on

I woul need to get with a query the first and last record grouping by node_id, ordering by id 
The result would have to be:

```
| 2610  | 1643  | 1645  |
| 2611  | 1647  | 1648  |
```

Comment: Ordering by the first id or last id?

Comment: The required result should be `| 2610  | 1643  | 1646  |` I suppose

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  node_id, MIN(id), MAX(id)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        node_id
```

Comment: Still waiting for the next instalment of Explain Extended. What's it been? Two years already! :-)

Comment: @Strawberry: sorry, I've been busy building a team. Patience and watch the space!

Comment: Oh, only just saw the 'earth from space' one. That looks amazing!

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you @Quassnoi

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where (id = (select max(id) from table_name) || id = (select min(id) from table_name))
```

Its will return two records.First a row having lowest id and second a record having highest id.